# VLookUp value to another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to get the value of the corresponding item in Lookup table. But, I am getting N/A in my output. In worksheet1, I need to use column H as a lookup value then reference it in VLookup sheet or Table2 using ColumnC, the corresponding value should get the value in ColumnD. I used this code:

```
=VLOOKUP(H2, Table2, 4, FALSE)
```

Is there something wrong in my code?

Sample value:

Screenshot for Sheet1:

[image]

Screenshot for VLookup
[image]

Comment: What is table2 defined as? Ie a1:c24...

Comment: Table2 defined as A1:G128

Comment: Then vlookup will be looking for its match in column A,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your vlookup to :

```
=VLOOKUP(H2,C2:D128,2, FALSE)
```

Or define Table3 as c2:D128...
and:

```
=VLOOKUP(H2, Table3, 4, FALSE)
```

To go the index & match route and it does have advantages, that the data does not have to be in the same area or even on the same sheet, I would suggest:

```
=index(sheet_name!D2:D128,MATCH(H2,sheet_name!C2:C128,0))
```

You can see the ranges defined in comparison to the vlookup, ie column D has the result, Column C the target...
See:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

VLOOKUP **always** looks in the first column of the lookup_range. It then return the corresponding value from the column to the right identified by column_num. If you aren't trying to find something in the first column then you need an INDEX/MATCH pair instead.

```
=index(table2[legend], match(h2, table2[function], 0))
```

You do not need to add the worksheet names if Table2 is a structured table. Table2 is a unique identifier and can be referenced across worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the formula
VLOOKUP(H2, 'Sheetname'!$C:$D,2, FALSE). 
Your formula will not work because the column(Column C in your case) that you are using to lookup the value is not the left most.